# What is the professional term for an image that separates between parts of a webpage?

Tags: website-design, text, images, terminology, accessibility

If you want to separate parts of a webpage in a website you could use a CSS `border` command or an HTML `<hr>` tag, but these designs could be a bit bland and you may want to use some **wide image** for that (cropped in mobile devices).
Something like these images, but even wider:

- [Image 1](https://depositphotos.com/vector/3d-data-technology-background-music-abstract-illustration-equalizer-for-music-showing-sound-waves-vector-design-250450510.html)
- [Image 2](https://depositphotos.com/illustration/blue-circuit-board-background-of-computer-motherboard-104146968.html)
- [Image 3](https://depositphotos.com/vector/abstract-blue-line-vector-background-46765047.html)

What is the professional term for an image that separates between parts of a webpage?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "separate parts of a webpage in a website with some image" if it's an image.. it's an image. Your link doesn't really provide any clarity. That link is not "separated by images" it is a collection of images separated by padding and margins.

Comment: @Scott Hello to you. Often a webpage is comprised of different parts and you want to visually separate them by a border line or an image. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Sorry.. I use padding and margins to separate HTML content in CSS. Using images is, well, bad in my view. they require additional http calls and thus slow page loads and take more memory. I honestly do not understand why *anyone* would be using *images* for "spacers". That seems like pretty horrible construction to me.

Comment: @Scott I see the point. I agree with you that it's better to avoid these and just style a `border` or an `<hr>` neatly. My problem is that in my particular content management system, Drupal (which is great in everything besides graphical design, unlike WordPress-Elementor for example), I don't have many choices left. I should probably upgrade my CSS knowledge.

Comment: I know Drupal.. you don't need images to create content separations. You simply need a CSS border property.

Comment: Why are you just adding more links to deposit photos??

Comment: Only these three to make sure people understand the question. No more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of HTML and web building,

A graphic element used to separate content is often called:

- A divider
- A separator

if the separator is more ornate in nature it may be called:

- an embellishment
- a flourish

All these terms are fairly universal and would relate to either web or print usage.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, these images are often named "line images".

For example, one can type into a **commercial image search engine** (in a website for image selling):

- `Red line`
- `Green line`
- `Blue line`

Even the non commercial Google Images and Bing Images found a small number of such images for these search queries.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. *Of course* search engines will find "red/green/blue line" results -  they are just colored lines. That does not explain what you mean by "separate by images". If you need a red line.. you can do that exclusively with CSS, you don't need any images.

Comment: I mean to something "very designed" not just a plain red line as with `border: 2px solid red`.

Comment: Well that last comment explains a LOT more than anything else. 

Comment: Oh cut me some slack will you, any attempt for me to graphically design anything generally meant tears for both me and the image manipulation program...

Comment: Sorry, not trying to give you a hard time. Everyone can have moments where they aren't explaining something well. .. just posting "designed.. not just a red line" makes a great deal more sense. I was thinking you were asking for some term for a "red line"... a simple line...

Comment: I do really apologize. Seems the initial question lead me down a thought path and I couldn't seen the "meaning" you were trying to convey. It wasn't until I read "more designed... not just a red line" that your intent dawned on me. The miscommunication is as much my fault as yours. Again. I apologize.

Comment: No problem, I as a non designer can even fault more...

Comment: I think I need a good book on CSS borders perhaps

Answer (score 0):

It may make sense to separate sections of a website with images in niche circumstances. For example, long articles that talk about a large subject or story may use images in the heading for each section. These act as section markers and / or breaks. They often are not the only images in the article.

As with most things, I don't think there's a specific name for images used in this way. It's  more common to describe their purpose and function.

With that being said, usually it doesn't make sense to load an image to divide regular sections of most webpages. That's what white space, using margin or padding, borders, and contrasting backgrounds are much better suited to do.